# PyQt5 & Qt Designer: why the second form displays a bad thing?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I can't make form1 to make parent object like it needs to be. 
And all content in second form align to left-top corner and i have no way to make it work fine. May be someone know what i can do with this. Thank you!

How it looks in Qt Designer:

[image: Designer]

But how it looks really:

[image: Real]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        uic.loadUi("mw.ui", self)
        uic.loadUi("form1.ui", self.mn_general)

        # Connect up the buttons.
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.BtnClck)
        self.show()

    def BtnClck(self):
        print('Hello StackOverflow')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Do you want to have form1 as a full window inside the main window (with title bar etc.)? If so, the only option is to create an MDI area, I think.

Comment: no, i'm no need to have titlebar and window(system) border. 
Just all content in form1 then it places in parent window align to left-top corner, and i can't make it like in designer.

Comment: But MDI area is the best way on the moment. Thanks!